# Symfony 1.4 - embedForm - new objects

Tags: forms, doctrine, symfony1, foreign-key-relationship

Here's my problem: I want to create a new instance of 'Resources' and directly create the instance of 'ResourceDescriptions' related to that one with a 1:n relation into one form.

Some background info:

1) simplified schema

```
ResourceDescriptions:
    connection: doctrine
    tableName: resource_descriptions
    columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    description:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations:
    Resources:
      local: id
      foreign: id
      type: one
Resources:
    connection: doctrine
    tableName: resources
    columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations:
        ResourceDescriptions:
          local: id
          foreign: id
          type: many
```

2) ResourcesForm

```
if ($this->getObject()->isNew()){
    $newDescription = new ResourceDescriptions();
    $newDescription->setResources($this->getObject());
    $newDescription->setId($this->getObject()->getId());
    $newDescriptionForm = new ResourceDescriptionsForm($newDescription);
    $this->embedForm('Description', $newDescriptionForm);
}
$this->embedRelation('ResourceDescriptions');
```

3) ResourceDescriptionsForm

```
public function configure(){

    $this->useFields(array('id', 'description'));

    $this->setWidgets(array('id' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array('default' => $this->getObject()->getId())), 'description' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),'expanded' => true,'multiple' => true),array('class' => 'checkbox'))));

    $this->setValidators(array('id' => new sfValidatorPass, 'description' => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 250)), 'multiple' => true))));

}
```

The problem here is that I want to get the id of an object of 'Resources' that hasn't been put into the database yet... Is there any way to get it before the insertion or an alternative way to be able to create the description at the same time (more or less) as the resource?

Comment: How is this about embedded computing/processors?

Comment: My bad, I have to remove that.

Comment: It looks like a one to one relation to me. Where is the FK column? I think you're missing one column line resource_id in ResourceDescriptions table. And this one should be the one in the relation.